# Silverlight 4 MVVM DataGrid AND Child Window Pass Data back to Parent Window

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I need Some help. I have a Silverlight application the parent form has a search button that when clicked loads a ModalDialog that has 3 text boxes, two button(for searchin and resetting) and a DataGrid (telerik gridview, but I can change it to any grid so not a problem). I enter a search criteria on one of the buttons, say the last name, and all the records with that particular lastname get loaded on the grid. I need to be able to select a row on the grid and having done so, the details of the selected row should be updated on the controls on the parent window (there is no grid on the parent window, its just like a data entry form). I am using MVVM. How do I acheive this while keeping true to the MVVM pattern? I have just seen alot of stuff on passing data from parent to child none on child to parent/calling window.

Any help, and some simple code example, will be highly appreciated. Been on it for a whole 3days and aint figuring it out as yet.

Francis.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the Mvvm light toolkit using messaging. It uses something called "PubSub", which means "Publish a message, Subscribe for a message"

I use a command in the GridView of my Modal window. Here's the XAML for that:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command={Binding ItemSelectedCommand} />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Depending on what flavor (if any) of MVVM toolkit you're using, the syntax might be different. In my case, as I said, MVVM light. Ultimately I'm using the iCommand interface to pass this command to my view model. In my case, the cmd reference is pointing to Galasoft.MvvmLight.Command:

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;Assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4"
```

In the ViewModel for my child window, I register for the command, and when it's triggered, I call this line:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<TSMVVM.Model.WorkOrders>(SelectedWorkOrder);
```

This line Publishes (sends) a message of type WorkOrders (which is a model class in my app), passing through the SelectedWorkOrder. This line of code sits inside of a Command, which is fired off on the SelectionChanged event of my gridview. Example code for this is:

```
_ItemSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(WorkOrderSelected);

private void WorkOrderSelected() 
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<TSMVVM.Model.WorkOrders>(SelectedWorkOrder);
}
```

In my parent window, in the constructor, I have this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<TSMVVM.Model.WorkOrders>(this, SetWorkOrder);
```

This line registers (or Subscribes) for a message of type WorkOrders. Any time a message is sent through my app, of type WorkOrder, it calls a function: SetWorkOrder, which is below:

```
private void SetWorkOrder(TSMVVM.Model.WorkOrders wo) 
    {
        this.SelectedWO = wo;
    }
```

My DataForm has an ItemsSource bound to WorkOrders, and a CurrentItem bound to SelectedWO, set with TwoWay binding. So when I update the SelectedWO (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, via Mvvm light toolkit's viewmodelbase), the DataForm updates accordingly.

If you need more info, let me know!

Scott